# echo to file with different user permission

Tags: shell-script, echo, tee

I'm trying to achieve a write into a file by a different user `root` as shown below.But the file is created and nothing written into it.

```
system("(echo 'ab' | su - root -c "echo 'Logging Enabled' |tee myLog.txt")>/dev/null");
```

Also tried `>` instead of `tee`

```
system("(echo 'ab' | su - root -c "echo 'Logging Enabled' > myLog.txt")>/dev/null");
```

Is there a better way of achieving this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this from within a C or a Perl program?

Comment: Yes in a C program

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear from your question which text you actually expect to end up in the file.

In the shell, you could do

```
echo 'ab' | sudo tee myLog.txt
```

to have "ab" written to `myLog.txt` and also displayed on standard output.  The reason to use `tee` is usually for its side effect, so that you don't have to run a shell as a privileged user, and the output to standard output is not actually desired; so you can add a redirect to suppress that.

```
echo 'ab' | sudo tee myLog.txt >/dev/null
```

In a *system***(3)** call in C code, you can simply put this in a string:

```
system("echo 'ab' | sudo tee myLog.txt >/dev/null");
```

The following is basically undefined:

```
echo 'ab' | echo 'Logging enabled'
```

but will typically simply discard "ab" because the second `echo` does not do anything with it, and instead produces its own output.  If you want to combine two pieces of text, try something like

```
printf "%s\nLogging enabled\n" "$(echo ab)"
```

but again, it is extremely unclear what and if so how you want to do with the two separate `echo` statements.

(To reiterate the obvious, `a | b` connects the standard output from `a` to the standard input of `b` and runs the two processes in parallel, with standard input still connected to the standard input of `a` and standard output coming from `b`.)

Comment: Ideally this statement works for me `system("echo 'Logging Enabled' |tee myLog.txt >/dev/null");` , but i want this operation to be performed as `root` user whose password is `ab`

Comment: Like outlined in the answer, the inner `echo` pipes into `su` and so whatever the outer `echo` prints is lost.  You can't really pipe into `su` and have it peel off just the first input as a password.

Comment: This is one of the many, many reasons `sudo´ instead would probably be a good idea.